# Reactive: Passing a method as a observer function parameter

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm getting a compilation error since I don't quite figure out how to do that:

```
public IObservable<X> Gather()
{
    this.vizs = vizs;
    return Observable.Create<X>(this.GetXObserver());
}
```

Where `getXObserver` is:

```
private IDisposable GetQueryObserver(IObserver<X> observer)
{
    //...
    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
}
```

How could I set that I want to use `GetXObserver` on `Observable.Create(...)` method?

What I want to get is avoid to create a code like:

```
Observable.Create<X>(
    observer =>
    {
        //long code here
    }
);
```

I would like to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The `public IObservable<X> Gather()` signature is invalid. Is it meant to be `public IObservable<X> Gather<X>()` or is it meant to be in a class with a generic type `X` or is there an actual type called `X`?

Comment: And you can't use an `IObserver<X>` in `Observable.Create<X>` - the signature for the parameter of `Create` is `Func<IObserver<X>, IDisposable>` - meaning that the lambda gives you the observable.

Comment: I've edited the post...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? That's the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: When the code inside lambda is too much long I prefer to create another method.

Comment: The only way is to recreate the signature in another method, but that then means that your code is longer and disjointed. It's a bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public IObservable<X> Gather()
{
    return Observable.Create<X>((Func<IObserver<X>, IDisposable>)GetXObserver);
}

private IDisposable GetXObserver(IObserver<X> observer)
{
    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
}
```

But it starts to make the code longer and disjointed. It's a bad design.

It seems to me that the following is cleaner:

```
public IObservable<X> Gather()
{
    return Observable.Create<X>(o => System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty);
}
```

That said, anytime you return `System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty` you are doing something wrong. It would be great if you could show your real code.